# presentmodalviewcontroller problem

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have a viewcontroller ticketsviewcontroller. when i do the below code cashrenderedview goes to some where. My requirement is keep the cashrendered controller in the same view (ticketsviewcontroller's view)

**code is :**

```
cashrendered *cashrend=[[cashrendered alloc] initWithNibName:@"cashrendered" bundle:nil]; 
[self presentModalViewController:cashrend animated:YES]; 
[cashrend.view setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 20, 300, 300)]; 
[cashrend release];
```

---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "goes to some where".

With your code, you can try:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:cashrend animated:YES];
```

Also, setting the frame wouldnt make sense for a modal view. If you are trying to achieve a view thats less than full screen, You should just use a custom view.

Comment: Besides, in Brad's code, will it actually crash since he releases the cashrend right after he presents it modally?

Comment: Try removing release and put in autorelease after init.

Comment: That release won't crash. I present all of my modal controllers that way. UIViewControllers retain their modalView property, which is set when presentModalViewController is called.